# What is a common verb we use to express one in a group tries to do things to make others in the group follow him/her?

Tags: word-request

Mary and Jen are children.

They play with each other, and Jen often says a lot and does not let Mary say much. Jen often suggests doing many things. Normally, Mary just follows what Jen asks her to do. Mary does not have many chances to express her ideas or do things she wants both of them do.

What is a common verb we use to express that one tries to do things to make others in the group follow him/her?

For example, *Jen dominates Mary*, or do we have a more common word to express it?

Comment: 'Jen always takes the lead in their games' would be an uncritical way to describe the situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are the verbs "to boss" and "to boss around" and someone can be "bossy".

> Jen is so bossy. She's always bossing Mary around.

Answer (score 1):

The following descriptions are quite strong:

> *does not let* Mary say much

> Mary *does not have many chances* to express her ideas

> to *make others* in the group follow him/her

Hence we could consider **dictate**:

> Jen **dictates** all their decisions.

Comment: Your analysis is good, because leadership is respectful where bullying is not.